# What analysis should I make when there is toppling question without specified axis?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, statics, stability

For example -

> What maximum weight can be put on a table of 20 kg and radius 1 m with massless leg which are symmetrically placed on circumference so, it doesn't topple?

Here, I don't know how to take axis and which equations to use. i first thought that the axis might be COM of legs but they are massless. is there any use of them?

Comment: You do know the axis. Since the table is circular its rim extends out past the line joining two adjacent legs, so a mass placed right on the edge can make the table topple. That line between the adjacent legs is the axis of rotation.

Comment: What will be the equations for the above example?